# How to add items to Quick Access when "Pin to Quick Access" doesn't work?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-quick-access

I use a Win10 instance for work and I'm unable to add anything to the Quick Access section in the sidebar of Explorer. The administrators have our user profile stored on the D:\ drive, which I *think* is what's causing this.

So where (whether it be registry or filepath) are the Quick Access menu items defined so I can try to add them that way?

Comment: You probably need to ask the Company.  Pin to Quick Access is working well here.  Windows likes Windows stuff being on Drive C.

Comment: If you are properly moving My Documents to another drive, pin to Quick Access from the relocated My Documents should still work. But do ask the Company.

Comment: Is there any message when you try?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere no there's no message--I right click the folder and click "Pin to Quick Access", but quick access still contains nothing in the sidebar

Comment: What if you simply drag a folder to the sidebar?